# UITableView reloadData not displaying correctly after deleting row

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, reloaddata

I have this code for a UITableView with two columns I found online. It works fine whenever I add another row to it, but when I pick a row to delete it just deletes the last row instead. I just add rows to the bottom of the array with [NSMutableArray addObject:], but when I delete a row I select the row to be removed first.

here is selecting the row ------( I checked to make sure tableViewIdx was correct)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   tableViewIdx = [indexPath row];
}
```

then the delete button ------( I checked to make sure the object was actually removed from the array)

```
-(IBAction)bt_DeletePressed:(id)sender{
    [mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:tableViewIdx];
    //delete actual content
    for(int i = VStableViewIdx;i<10;i++){
        g_vitals[i] = g_vitals[i+1];
    }
    [TableView reloadData];
    tableViewIdx--;
}
```

and some of the tableView code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   int count = [listData count];
   if(self.editing) count++;
   tableSize = count;
   return count;
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];

   MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil){
       cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];

       NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
       [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

       UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 60.00,tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
       [cell addColumn:60];
       label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
       label.text = textView.text;
       [formatter release];
       label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
       label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
       label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
       [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; 

       label =  [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 0, 60.0,tableView.rowHeight)] autorelease];
       [cell addColumn:500];
       label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
       label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",respRateTemp];
       label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
       label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
       label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
       [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
   }

   return cell;
}
```

Any ideas why it would be removing the last row, instead of the selected one?

EDIT: I was actually able to fix it myself, by using deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: instead of updateData, however now I have another problem. My program runs fine on the simulator, but crashes frequently on a device. It comes up with the error:

Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Can't find dlopen function, so it is not possible to load shared libraries.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" delegate. 
According to your logic tableview dequeueReusableCells with index numbers, which causes the missing of the last row instead the selected row to delete. May be you can change the logic in cellForRowAtIndexPath or you can use a proper data structure & algorithms to manage the table view.